# How do you pass parameters to a controller method when you invoke it in the Rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, console, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Rails 5.  I have this controller ...

```
class MyObjectsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    my_object = MyService.build(create_params)
```

I would like to call the create method in the rails console but I get this error ...

```
irb(main):007:0> MyObjectsController.new.create(:id => "abc")
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from (irb):7
        1: from app/controllers/my_objects_controller.rb:4:in `create'
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0))
```

How do I pass parameters to my controller method?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You're getting this error because the **create** method doesn't receive any argument. In order to use the create action properly you need to pass the ActionController::Parameters to your controller's instance:

```
c = MyObjectsController.new
c.params = ActionController::Parameters.new(id: "abc")
c.create # It will not work if this controller uses authentication
```

Comment: This "answer" would be better with some context. Also this `new({id: "abc"})` can be just this `new(id: "abc")`. Is always better typing less.

Comment: The controller function indeed runs, but when it tries to render, it throws DelegationError. Any way to solve it?

Comment: And what to do in that case where it uses authentication?

Comment: Roughly speaking you could write ```c.request = ActionDispatch::Request.new({})``` and ```c.request.headers['Authorization'] = 'YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN'```. But depending on how you're authenticating your users, maybe this isn't enough.

Answer (score 1):

If the requirement is to call action method of a controller having request method as POST via rails console and pass parameters in it, then it can be done via following commands

```
# Request any of the application resource, for example root url to get authenticity token
app.get '/'
token = app.session[:_csrf_token]

# parameters to send
parameters = { my_object: { field_one: 'foo', field_two: 'bar' }, authenticity_token: token }

# Call controller method
app.post '/my_objects', params: parameters
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

> app.post "?create_params[id]=abc"

For example

> app.post '/users?user[name]=test&user[age]=20'

will pass the following
{"user"=>{"name"=>"test", "age"=>"20"}}

Answer (score 0):

`params` in Rails can't access everywhere. Params in Rails can only access from class inherited from `ActionController::Base`, so in Rails console you cannot access your `params`, but you can access `params` via a public method.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your controller action as follows:

```
def my_actions(myparams=nil)
  @loginid = myparams.nil? ? params[:login_id] : myparams[:login_id] 
end
```

This way you can test your controller in rails console by passing your params.